# do swift throwing functions block main thread?

Tags: ios, swift, try-catch, throws

in swift if a long running throwing function is called from the main thread will I be blocking my UI? Or do throwing functions occur asynchronously automatically?  Just wondering if I should dispatch it off the main thread or if that will be redundant.

Comment: a throwing function is not different from any other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function will run on which ever queue you call it on. If it is a long running function as you say I would suggest firing it off on a background queue so that you don't risk it tying up your main queue.

If you would like more background info (pun intended) checkout Objc.IO article [Concurrency APIs on OS X and iOS](https://www.objc.io/issues/2-concurrency/concurrency-apis-and-pitfalls/)

This diagram is from the article and quite useful for visualizing queues.
[image]